# How can I plot a graph at the end of the function

Tags: graph, octave

I need to implement a script where the user enters information for multiple samples. I need to draw a graph with that information, but I need to plot it with all information at the end of the execution. My actual script plots one graph every time the user enters information for one of the samples.

```
op=input('Digite a quantidade de compostos:');
i=1;
j=1;
k=1;
temp =0:5:100
while(i<=op)
  produto=input('Digite o nome do produto:','s');
  quant(i)=input('Digite a quantidade de amostras:')
  lista{i}=produto; 
  for j =1:quant(i)
    amostras(j,k)=input('Digite o valor da solubilidade:')
    k++;
    amostras(j,k)=input('Digite o valor da temperatura:')
    k=1;
  end 
  hold all;
  gplot(amostras,amostras);
  i++
end
hold off;
```

Comment: I tried to fix up the grammar. I hope I didn't change the meaning of your paragraph, please [edit] the question if I messed it up! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `'Visible'` property of the figure to hide it during the execution of your loops and show it later.

So insert this before your `while` loop:

```
figure();
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off');
```

and now at the end of your code, make it visible again with:

```
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'on');
```

Answer (score 2):

> [...] I need to plot it with all information at the end of the execution. My actual script plots one graph every time the user enters information for one of the samples.

Don't plot it each time. Store the values and plot everything at the end instead.  Like so:

```
op = input ('Digite a quantidade de compostos: ');
lista = cell (op, 1);
amostras = cell (op, 1);

for i = 1:op
  lista = input ('Digite o nome do produto: ','s'); 
  quant = input ('Digite a quantidade de amostras: ');
  amostras{i} = zeros (quant, 1);
  for j = 1:quant
    amostras{i}(j,1) = input ('Digite o valor da solubilidade: ');
    amostras{i}(j,2) = input ('Digite o valor da temperatura: ');
  endfor
endfor
## plot now
```